# Uncaught TypeError with Redux Form and Immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, redux-form

When I use `redux-form@7.0.4` with `immutable@3.8.1` I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _immutable.isCollection) is not a function

Tried also version:

```
redux-form@7.1.0 with immutable@3.8.2,
redux-form@7.0.4 with immutable@3.8.2,
redux-form@7.1.0 with immutable@4.0.0-rc.7
```

I am using React16.

Comment: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3488 I think this helps you.

Comment: Fixed - the problem fixed after upgrade the npm version from 3.X to 5

Answer (score 1):

Per @NarasimhaReddy's comment:

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3488

Redux-form@7.10.0 requires immutable@4.0.0-rc.7 or higher.
It introduced a breaking change that made it incompatible with immutable@3.8.2

The real culprit here is a mistake in applying the [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning).
If your dependency is defined as `"redux-form": "^7.0.4"`, then npm expects that it can use any version between `7.0.4` - `8.0.0`.

When you run `npm install` it will grab the latest version in this range, expecting there are no breaking changes.